# Tracker User Session With Cookies and Not JS Like Google

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, google-analytics, mixpanel

Some background, the environment I am working in is PHP on the server side and Javascript on the client side. To track a user session, I make a JS PUT request to a server every 5 seconds. Through this I get the amount of time they were on the site, scroll depth, click events, etc.

With tools such as MixPanel or Google Anaylytis, they have the same metrics being measured, yet there isn't constant js calls being made. So my question is how are they tracking the user without javascript?

Comment: The only way to track the user like this is with javascript. There isn't another method to get all that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question seems to be... "how does google analytics know how long a user spends on a site without sending constant updates"? Well, short answer is that **it doesn't** (but it can, read on...!)

In the simplest setup, it will create a session when the first page is opened. Then it will track the time until the second page is opened, then the third. But it doesn't know when the third page was closed, so the total time for the session will only be "time page 3 was opened" minus "time page 1 was opened". And that's what you'll see on the analytics page. This is how most analytics systems work and yes, it's innaccurate. But that's how it is.

HOWEVER! There is a way around this, and it's called an "engagement hit" - essentially just tracking when a user does something on your page, e.g. playing a video or clicking a banner. In fact, you can track all sorts of events with Google Analytics and this will all help towards accurately reporting time-spent. This will involve more JS calls being made than just the typical onload event, but they certainly will not be constant (unless you set up some crazy events).

There's some good information about this on the [GA docs site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide?hl=en). It might be worth having a look and trying to implement something similar.